# Cost per dose of medicine to increase malaria prophylaxis coverage by one-percent

Tags: analysis, percentages, data-analysis

Suppose I want to calculate the cost per dose for a one percent increase in malaria prophylaxis coverage for a group of kids that received a malaria program that dispensed medicine cheaply as compared with a control group of kids who did not receive such a program.

I run a randomized trial, I estimate:

C_d = cost per dose of malaria medication given to kids in the program
P_m = percentage difference in malaria prophylaxis coverage for (treatment - control)

Can I get the cost per dose for a one percent increase in malaria prophylaxis coverage by simply dividing (C_d / P_m) ?

Comment: It might make more sense to look at the difference in total cost rather than the difference in cost *per dose*, as presumably the number of doses changes if coverage changes

Comment: This cost measures the cost of the program per dose of malaria medicine provided. Not all kids in the program will take the doses. So it makes sense in the context where we want to compare cost-effectiveness of different programs that have the same goal.

Comment: Wait. I figured it out. I need to convert the % I calculated to an absolute percent increase, which entails multiplying p_m*100, then dividing into cost per malaria dose per kiddo.